# How do I install Multilingual User Interface (MUI) for Terminal Services on Windows 2008 Server (not R2)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-vista

Windows Server is based on Vista, so most guides online are useless.  Moreover, the Microsoft download page that allows me to download the image file (which presumably contains the language pack CABs) has broken links for the install instruction pages :(

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22681

I want either the user to be able to select the language (although they have very limited permissions), or I can manually set them (perhaps as a group policy).

I am remote, so hopefully I don't need to burn this .img file I downloaded (although maybe I can virtually mount it).

NOTE: Also, this is on VMWare.  I'm not sure that matters.  I have no idea how the VMWare works yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to download at least a few of those images. Inside those images are the specific .cab files for installing language support. On the download page, there is a chart specifying which languages are on which image files.

The [Windows Vista MUI Step-by-Step guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722391%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is available and should be adequate documentation for the procedure on a Server 2008 installation.  The process itself is quite involved, so replicating the documentation here is not feasible.

Comment: Isn't there a way to just add the cab files to an existing installation?  The steps you linked included creating a new windows server installation disk, and running it.